# How to share the image and the AVI file by using ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE?

Tags: android, android-intent

The scenario of mine is:

I select the multiple item from `Gridview`.

When I click the `share button` , it will show the item like: E-mail , Bluetooth , Message , FaceBook.

Like the following picture.

[image]

I have reference the [Android-developer](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) , but I still don't know how to do.

And the code in my share button is like the following:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ArrayList<FileNode> MultiUri = new ArrayList<FileNode>();

        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = fileListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
         if (checkedItems != null) {
             for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
                    if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {

                        int temp_position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);                      
                        final FileNode fileNode = mFileList.get(temp_position) ;

                        MultiUri.add(fileNode);
                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                        shareIntent.setAction(shareIntent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                        shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) MultiUri);
                        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to.."));

                    }
                }
         }
    }
```

And the error log is like the following:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 4114): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 4114): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416cc450)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.FileBrowser.Model.FileNode@42353850
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1240)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1200)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:596)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:610)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6519)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1259)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1178)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:596)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:610)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6519)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1741)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3850)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3825)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:996)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:975)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.FileBrowser.LocalFileBrowserFragment$3.onClick(LocalFileBrowserFragment.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4114):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  568):   Force finishing activity tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/.MainActivity
```

And the `LocalFileBrowserFragment.java:214` is `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to.."));`

How to get the Uri and add to the intent if I use the File and FileNode?

And how to do the next ?

Comment: How to get the Uri and add to the intent ?

Comment: Are you trying to post the image on social media ?

Comment: share with E-mail , Message , Facebook...like the picture

Comment: Do you want to share picture on multiple medias only single time by selecting multiple medias ?

Comment: NO , share multiple picture with E-mail or Message or Facebook. It can choose by user.

Comment: From where you are taking image ?

Comment: The image is save in my phone , and I can select it from a Gridview. So I can get the position of item on Gridview. But I don;t know how to turn it to Uri. I have use final FileNode fileNode = mFileList.get(temp_position) ;
                                                File file = new File(fileNode.mName) ;

Comment: Are you selecting image from Gallery ? Please post the sufficient code .

Comment: No , I select image from Gridview !The code is to long

Comment: How to get the Uri and add to the intent if I use the File and FileNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `Android.Uri` from file.

```
File file = new File(path, filename);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

If you want to get URI instance, then do the following

```
File file = new File(path, filename);
URI uri = file.toURI();
```